# HTML file at the root of tomcat server using struts2

Tags: tomcat, struts2, struts, tomcat6

I'm using struts 2. I want to put googleverfication.htm file permanently at the root of our website for verification of website via Google websmaster tool.

I'm using tomcat 6 server.

How can do this?

I kept the file at the root & hit https://myurl.com/googleverfication.htm But nothing is coming up. Request is not going at all.

Do I need to add the entry in struts.xml or web.xml?

Note: I've CAS server filter within web.xml for url pattern as /*

Thanks!

Comment: why don't you use verification code being provided by Google and place it in header section which is more flexible

Comment: What is a "CAS server filter"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've overridden the default servlet by mapping /* to something, then that servlet will respond to requests for "/googleverfication.htm". If you want to allow the /real/ default servlet to respond to requests for that file, try this in your web.xml file:

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/googleverfication.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

If your "CAS server filter" is interfering, you might want to make an exception for that URL pattern (either in web.xml, by mapping it differently, or by configuring the filter to ignore that particular URL pattern and pass-through the request to the rest of the filter chain).